# Immediately run a function on page load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a simple memory game. Right now, the box colors are hard coded. I have a "Reset" button which randomizes all the colors on click.

What I want to do it simply run this reset button functionality as soon as the page loads, so that the colors will be randomized every time the game is opened.

I have tried implementing window.onload but nothing seems to work. What is the best approach to implementing this update?

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-bardeen-g3wfu?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Box({thing, index, style, updateStatus}){
  return(
    <button type="button" className="Box" style={style(index)} onClick={() => updateStatus(index)}>
      <div>
        {thing[index].status}
      </div>
    </button>
  )
}

function Reset({newColors, colors, thing}){
  return(
    <button type="button" onClick={() => newColors(colors, thing)}>
      Reset
    </button>
  )
}

function App() {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState([
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false},
      {status: null, clicked: false}
    ]);

    const [color, setColor] = useState(['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'orange', 'orange', 'pink', 'pink', 'purple', 'purple', 'white', 'white', 'green', 'green'])

    const [holder, setHolder] = useState([])

    const [lockBoard, setLockBoard] = useState(false); /* lock board */

    function delayedResolve(ms){
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve()
        }, ms);
      });
    }

    async function updateStatus(index) {
      if (lockBoard) return; /* lock board */
      if (!status[index].clicked) {
        const newStatus = [...status];
        newStatus[index].clicked = true;

        let newHolder = [...holder, { index, color: color[index] }];

        setStatus(newStatus);

        if (newHolder.length === 2) {
          setLockBoard(true); /* lock board */
          if (!holderTest(newHolder)) {
            await delayedResolve(1000)
            newHolder.map((x) => {
            newStatus[x.index].clicked = false;
          });
          }
          newHolder = [];
        }
        setLockBoard(false)
        setHolder(newHolder);
      }
    }

console.log(holder.length)
console.log(holder)
console.log(status)

/*    function misMatch(newHolder){
      return (newHolder.map((x) => {
        newStatus[x.index].clicked = false;
      }))
    } */

    function holderTest(holderToTest){
      if (holderToTest[0].color === holderToTest[1].color){return true}
    }

    function colorChange(index){
        return (
          {backgroundColor: status[index].clicked ? color[index] : 'black'})
    }

    function resetColor(array, array2) {
        const newColors = [...array]
        const newArray = [...array2]

        for (var i = newColors.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = newColors[i];
            newColors[i] = newColors[j];
            newColors[j] = temp;
        }

        newArray.map((x) => {x.clicked = false})

        return setColor(newColors), setStatus(newArray)
    }

    return (
          <div>
            <Reset newColors={resetColor} colors={color} thing={status}/>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="column">
                <Box thing={status} index={0} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={1} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={2} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={3} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
              </div>
              <div className="column">
                <Box thing={status} index={4} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={5} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={6} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={7} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
              </div>
              <div className="column">
                <Box thing={status} index={8} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={9} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={10} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={11} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
              </div>
              <div className="column">
                <Box thing={status} index={12} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={13} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={14} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
                <Box thing={status} index={15} style={colorChange} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you want to build a "**simple** memory game"  - but you're using ReactJS. I sense a contradiction. Nothing in any modern JavaScript UI framework is simple.

Comment: Generally speaking, when you're using a large JavaScript UI framework like AngularJS, Angular, ReactJS, Vue, etc you should not use DOM events directly - you always have to go through the framework. Otherwise things break in horrible ways.

Comment: In this case you should probably stick to using React hooks and do something like `useEffect(() => resetColor(...), [])` so that it is executed once right after component mount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the `useEffect` hook with no dependencies added in the array. So it runs only on page load.

```
useEffect(() => {
  resetColor(color, status);
}, []);
```

On a side note, you should wrap your `resetColor` in a `useCallback` with dependencies `[color, status]`. Seems that there is no need to pass the `color` and `status` to your `<Reset />` component. If you make use of the `useCallback` as mentioned you will already have access to the latest values of `color` and `status` so you can remove them from the function arguments.